# Unable to populate column in dataframe using value from dict which is present in dict inside list in one of the column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, floating-point

[image]I have one column in data frame with values like this List with dictionary inside

```
[{'symbol': '$', 'value': 5.2, 'currency': 'USD', 'raw': '$5.20', 'name': '$5.20$5.20 ($1.30/Fl Oz)', 'asin': 'B07N31VZP8']
```

I want only 'value' from this dictionary.

```
for i in df["prices"]:
    try:
        #print(type(i[0]["value"]))
        df["prices"] = df["prices"].apply(lambda i:i[0]["value"])
    except Exception as e:
        print("",e)
```

but I'm getting the following error even if I was able to get that value, I cant populate it in dataframe column

```
'float' object is not subscribable
```

How to overcome this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you apply the transformation multiple times. The `apply()` already applies the transformation for every row in your dataframe. If you remove the loop it should work:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create your data
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['test',[{'symbol': '$', 'value': 5.2, 'currency': 'USD', 'raw': '$5.20', 'name': '$5.20$5.20 ($1.30/Fl Oz)', 'asin': 'B07N31VZP8'}]]
    , ['test',[{'symbol': '$', 'value': 6.8, 'currency': 'USD', 'raw': '$5.20', 'name': '$5.20$5.20 ($1.30/Fl Oz)', 'asin': 'B07N31VZP8'}]]
], columns=['test','prices'])

print(df)

df["prices"] = df["prices"].apply(lambda i:i[0]["value"])

print(df)
```

Input dataframe:

```
   test                                             prices
0  test  [{'symbol': '$', 'value': 5.2, 'currency': 'US...
1  test  [{'symbol': '$', 'value': 6.8, 'currency': 'US...
```

Output dataframe:

```
   test  prices
0  test     5.2
1  test     6.8
```

Comment: I have to update values in all rows

Comment: `apply` applies the lambda function on every row in the column. As you can see in my example it applies it on both rows. I updated the values and you can see it extracts `5.2` in the first row and `6.8` in the second one. If there are any differences in the rows it would be helpful to add a larger input to your question.